# Windows 10 doesn't boot after Ubuntu 17.04 installation

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot

Hey Super Users: I installed an Ubuntu 17.04 on my Laptop (Dell 5567) both OS installed on Bios mode and not UEFI. I have both OS on boot menu but when I click on Windows 10, the screen just flashing and nothing happens. But my Ubuntu boot and work without any problems. I already tried Boot-repair but it's not help. What should I do to recover my windows 10 again ?

Comment: Try booting in safe mode. Hit Escape or F8 while window is about to boot. Either of those keys should work.

Comment: @Shiva I don't understand what should I do, after Dell logo appears then the boot menu showed up. an then I could choose between Ubuntu and windows, when I chose windows nothing happens except one time screen flash. When should I press F8 and why ? What should I do then ?

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you have to fix:

1. Windows boot
2. Ubuntu boot

in that order.

Windows should be able to boot alone without the help/interaction of GRUB (Ubuntu loader)

After that Windows can boot alone you have to reinstall GRUB so it can take over the boot process and chain load Windows if selected in boot menu.

For fixing Windows 7/8/10 boot with USB/DVD you can use two simple commands:

1. `bootsect /nt60 all /MBR`
2. `bcdboot v:\windows /s Z:`

V: is Windows partition, Z: is active partition

Change drive letters in example to your drive mappings.

Then [fix GRUB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) with live CD/USB.

Help on [fixing Windows boot](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/repair-windows-boot.html).

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. Now, even get worse. After trying to fix windows boot with you command on command prompt I can't see the boot menu anymore and only a black screen with a flashing line in the right top. So I can't boot neither windows nor Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you post the output of diskpart commands: 1) "list disk" 2) "sel disk 0" and then "lis par"

Comment: Sorry i just had to remove everything, install new windows and then new ubuntu, i haven't anymore to upload any picture.

Comment: A fresh Windows installation runs at top speed. You can use some backup tool "To Do A Complete Backup of your current Windows installation", and later maybe monthly repeat the complete (or differential) backup so you don't lose much work in case something goes wrong with your installations.